# Physical significance of the angular velocity vector and its projections along different axes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

Let's say there is a disk spinning at angular velocity $\omega$. If an observer looks down at the disk directly from the top, he will see the red marker spinning about the center of the disk at angular velocity $\omega$.
[image]

If the observer now looks at the disk at an angle $\theta$ concerning vertical, the angular velocity observed would then be $\omega\cos\theta < \omega$. However, to the observer, the period of the red dot will remain the same, meaning that it does not spin slower?

How can we resolve this paradox, thank you?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude andis not direction of the angular velocity $\vec\omega$ remains the same in the both cases you proposed. The projection of this vector into any axis is, of course, depending on the coordinate system. The projection component has no directly physics meaning.  The spinning frequency is dependent on $\lvert \vec\omega \rvert$, which is not changed in both cases.

On the contrary, the angular momentum $$ \vec L= \int \rho(\vec r) d^3r\,\, \vec r \times \vec v(\vec r)$$ is apparently depends on the coordinate system employed. Similarly, the torque $$\vec \tau = \sum_i \vec r_i \times \vec F_i. $$
Absolute values of $\vec L$ and $\vec \tau$ are dependent on the coordinate system. Only the relation between them $$ \vec \tau = \frac{d\vec L}{dt}$$
is independent of coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is your case. you are outside the disk object. With your eyes you can’t change the rotation of the disk, you just can look from other direction of view.

Answer (score 0):

There is only *one* rotation axis and speed. It does not matter where the observer is.

As far as the apparent motion of a particle on a spinning disk it will follow an ellipse (non constant rotation) since they view is described by a cone which the plane of motion cuts at an oblique angle, and from the theory of conic sections the result is an ellipse.